C# GoogleSheetsApi Error: The service sheets has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is NotFound. Requested entity was not found
I have a problem, GoogleSheetsApi does not see the table, despite the fact that it is configured and should work. I tried everything and couldn't solve the problem. Tell me, maybe someone knows a solution to the problem?
I tried different options, changed the Api key, tried inserting another table and even changed the architecture code, but it didn't get me anywhere.
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly GoogleSheetsService _googleSheetsService;
    private readonly List<CartItem> _cart = new List<CartItem>();

    public MainWindow(GoogleSheetsService googleSheetsService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // API 
        string apiKey = "";

        _googleSheetsService = new GoogleSheetsService(new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = apiKey,
            ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API"
        }), apiKey);

        LoadProducts();
    }

    private async void LoadProducts()
    {
        try
        {
            string spreadsheetId = "";

            var values = await _googleSheetsService.GetValuesAsync("Sheet1!A2:C", spreadsheetId);
            if (values != null && values.Count() > 0)
            {
                var products = values.Select(v => new Product
                {
                    Name = v[0].ToString(),
                    Quantity = int.Parse(v[1].ToString()),
                    Price = decimal.Parse(v[2].ToString())
                }).ToList();

                ProductsDataGrid.ItemsSource = products;
            }
        }
        catch (Google.GoogleApiException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private void AddToCart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var product = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Product;
        if (product != null)
        {
            var cartItem = _cart.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == product.Name);
            if (cartItem != null)
            {
                cartItem.Quantity++;
            }
            else
            {
                _cart.Add(new CartItem { Name = product.Name, Quantity = 1, Price = product.Price });
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Added to cart");
        }
    }

    private void ViewCartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CartWindow cartWindow = new CartWindow(_googleSheetsService, _cart);
        cartWindow.Show();
    }
}


is the sheet public?

No, access to the sheet is enabled by link, in this way other tables that are in the application work

To access the api you need to use Oauth2 and have the owner of the file grant access to your applicaiton.
